# Что от меня хочет Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

ДВС!
Преобразую столбец df командой:

```
use_table['openPrice'] = pd.to_numeric(use_table['openPrice'], errors='coerce')
```

Но pandas выдает предупреждение

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  use_table['openPrice'] = pd.to_numeric(use_table['openPrice'], errors='coerce')
```

Код работает, но напрягает это сообщение. Что он от меня хочет? Я так понимаю, он предлагает более правильный вариант, но как его написать, я не понимаю... Помогите пожалуйста)

Comment: а вы пробовали пройти по ссылке? Ну или на крайний случай перевести сообщение которое вы нам приводите?))

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, читал. Но, что то я туплю, не понимаю как через .loc преобразовать столбец

Comment: А прям в лоб скопипастить с сайта и заменить имена пробовали? :) ```use_table.loc[:,('openPrice')]```?

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, конечно пробовал. После преобразование идет сравнение столбца с 0, при использовании use_table.loc[:,('openPrice')] падает в ошибку. И выдает тоже самое предупреждение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле проблема, как это иногда бывает, не в той строке, к которой показывается предупреждение. Воспроизведу проблему:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6]})
use_table = df[df['a'] > 1]
use_table['b'] = use_table['b'] + 1
```

Выходит то самое предупреждение:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

Почему так? Потому что `use_table` - это срез таблицы `df`. И тут возможно два решения - либо вас устраивает, что вы работаете со срезом, вы не хотите возвращаться к таблице `df`, не хотите в неё вносить изменения. Тогда просто скопируйте таблицу после выборки по условию и предупреждения дальше уже не будет - теперь это новая, отдельная таблица:

```
use_table = df[df['a'] > 1].copy()
```

Либо, если вы всё же хотите работать с исходной таблицей, и вносить изменения в неё, то и вносить изменения нужно именно в неё, в данном примере это будет так:

```
df.loc[df['a'] > 1, 'b'] = df.loc[df['a'] > 1, 'b'] + 1
```

Зачастую это предупреждение можно игнорировать - изменения попадут и в `use_table` и в `df` и вы именно этого и хотели. Но всё же лучше не игнорировать предупреждения и делать всё правильно, чётко понимая, что вы делаете. `Pandas` ругается не просто так, у него есть сомнения, что вы понимаете, что вы делаете.

Comment: Спасибо, Вам, золотой Вы человек=) Проблема была именно в том, что я использовал срез таблицы, поправил предыдущий код и все заработало!